# Hide grouping row in slickgrid

Tags: javascript, css, slickgrid

Is there any option to not show grouping header in SlickGrid?

1) I tried to just set it to

```
.slick-group{
    display:none;
}
```

but all normal rows have set top inline:

```
<div class="ui-widget-content slick-row even slick-group" style="top:50px"...
```

That means that even grouping row not shown anymore, the space between grouped row blocks left. So thats not solves my problem.

2)I've found question where one guy hides total row using dataView parameter `displayTotalsRow: false`. And i wonder maybe there is some displayTotalsRow like paramenter, that hides grouping row?